# how to enable cachemgr_passwd and auth_param at the same time in squid proxy?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, http-proxy, squid

i have issue when try implement cachemgr_passwd and auth_param at the same time

i use ubuntu 20.04 and squid Version 3.5.12

this below config from squid.conf

```html
http_port 3128

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443

acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports

acl CONNECT method CONNECT

cachemgr_passwd p455wd all

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/.htpasswd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Basic Authentication
auth_param basic credentialsttl 5 hours
acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow password

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
#http_access deny manager

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

coredump_dir /squid/var/cache/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

i can use proxy with basic auth, but i cant access squid-internal-mgr with config above, i try to access cachegmr page but always get 407  like image on attach after visit url below, i also put log squid access below

- http://10.168.0.110:3128/squid-internal-mgr/counters

squid access log:

```html
1640361341.893      0 192.168.219.10 TCP_DENIED/407 4629 GET http://staging-app1:3128/squid-internal-mgr/counters - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1640361351.010      0 192.168.219.10 TCP_DENIED/407 4629 GET http://staging-app1:3128/squid-internal-mgr/counters - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1640361351.601      0 192.168.219.10 TCP_DENIED/407 4629 GET http://staging-app1:3128/squid-internal-mgr/counters - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1640361351.869      0 192.168.219.10 TCP_DENIED/407 4629 GET http://staging-app1:3128/squid-internal-mgr/counters - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXiCi.png)

if i delete basic auth_param, i can access page squid-internal-mgr with password

maybe someone can help me for give correct config if i want enable cachemgr_passwd and auth_param at the same time?